# How to tell my coworker that I am mad at her?

Tags: colleagues

I asked a question in a session and one of my coworkers said "our question is not very important and we should not speak about it in this session" ... and then I agreed politely but I am mad at her and I can not tell her this and I can not control my sadness ...I want to tell her act more respectfully and if my question is not in the scope of that session , use better sentences and be more polite ... even though I don't agree that my question is not in the scope of the session and I can not say this because I am not enough senior but I want to learn how to speak politely and actively in sessions and meetings... but the most important point is that I am still mad at my coworker and when I am working with her that sadness will affect to my work and I can not speak with her ... she has this behavior with others and I know other peaple in my office have the same issue with her but nobody speak with her about this and I think it is because of the friendship between her and our boss... what should I do now please help me?
thanks for all of the comments and answers all of them will help me alot

Comment: Is your coworker more senior than you?

Comment: yes she is @GregoryCurrie

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I am sorry but I could not get your point ... would you please explain more?

Comment: What do you hope to gain by telling her?

Comment: Well, firstly you need to determine if your anger is rational, and then you need to figure out how to articulate it, and then you need to figure out how you would prefer they acted in the future. Then knowing these things, you go speak with them, if you think it's worth it.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I know I should speak with her but I can not start speaking politely... when I am mad at someone I can not control my sadness specially in this case that she is more senior than me

Comment: @Helena I feel if she knows about it she will not speak like this in the next sessions

Comment: @FatemehAzizkhani You probably need to articulate why you feel anger (or sadness) in the question.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie thank you very much your answer is helpful and I will think to it

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I know and because of that I am still silent but I don't want to be a person who can not control herself in such situations and I want to learn how to control my madness and speak politely

Comment: You need to keep in mind that even if somebody acts unprofessionally, that doesn't mean you have a right to act unprofessionally back. I'm not saying they acted unprofessional here though.

Comment: @FatemehAzizkhani What is the alternative action you would want her to take? Do you disagree that your question was not important for that specific meeting and you would like your questions to be discussed, or do you want her to use a more respectful tone of voice?

Comment: This is not a question of "more senior or not" but of the rest of this situation. How was is said, could the question really be delayed, was the session about something very different and perhaps in a hurry...

Comment: @puck The way I look at it is someone more senior to me can shut down any question, and that's it. A peer should probably only suggest it's out of scope, and give me a chance to agree before we all move on.

Comment: This may be a better fit for Interpersonal Skills. The problem seems more about the asker's emotional issues.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie isn't that one of reasons why some companies go down?

Comment: @puck Maybe it is. But I wouldn't get angry about it.

Comment: Why the hell is this being downvoted? Because you disagree with OP's reaction? It's a valid question and the answers can help a lot. To your point @Helena: When something bothers you it is better to have a "small battle" right then and there, rather than bottle it up so that it explodes later. For whatever reason, this occupies OP's mind.

Comment: Welcome to The Workplace @Fatemeh Azizkhani.I'm placing your question on hold to clarify what your main question is: dealing with a colleague's feedback in a workplace situation, or dealing with an emotional reaction in a personal interaction. The latter is outside our scope and may be more appropriate for [interpersonal.se]. Please check the [tour] and [help/on-topic] to learn more about the sort of questions we can handle here.

Comment: @Lilienthal What about an emotional reaction to a workplace interaction? ;)

Comment: @Lilienthal My point is, you're asking OP to articulate her feelings before the question can be answered. The problem is, the question _will_ be answered once those feelings are articulated. I'm all for the Socratic method, but let's give OP a fighting chance here, shall we?

Comment: @rath I totally agree with speaking up, if something bothers you. 
To answer how to bring it up, we need to know what the situation is and what OP would like the alternative to be and the question lacks that kind of detail. That's why I am asking clarifying questions.

Comment: @rath If the question is clarified to explicitly ask that, then I don't see an issue to reopen it. But in its present form it would be mostly guesswork to figure out what the key question or problem is and whether it's truly on-topic here.

Answer (score 8):

If you asked a question in a meeting that was out of scope for the meeting, and somebody more senior tells you this isn't important now, then that's just something you'll have to deal with because it happens to us all.

We all have those moments in a meeting where we raise a question that doesn't really need to be asked, and we usually get different variants of "let's discuss this later".

Depending on the difference in seniority, the importance of the question, how much the meeting is running over, the response may vary from very polite, to very brusque.

As you become more and more senior this becomes more rare because:

- You gain a better understanding of what's important
- People give you more latitude

It's only human to feel negative emotions from time to time. But we need to try to think why we feel these things. If we are upset because the tone of the statement was a bit too direct on one occasion, we need to think about if it's worthwhile kicking up a fuss.

Only you can control your own emotions. You should try not to let bad feelings linger. Especially if this has only happened once.

If there is a pattern of disrespect, that is a different story.

Comment: Of course, there is the situation that the point being raised **is** important but the manager wants it shutdown so they can take credit later...

Comment: That seems way more unlikely than "A senior already knows the point is not important and does not want to waste everyone's time by discussing it in the meeting, but will address if afterwards." Done this many times, it's actually quite normal.